# ASP.net Webforms with ASP.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, ado.net, asp.net-identity

I am thinking of building a Login /Authentication module using ASP.net Identity. Most of tutorial what I have seen uses Entity Framework with Identity framework.

Is it possible to use ADO.net(I know its old) with Identity Framework ?

Comment: ADO.NET is old, but Entity Framework is built on top of it. Age isn't really relevant. I guess the question is more: why? Why write the data access logic yourself? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Goal is to add Identity framework and get rid of old membership in to existing project which uses ADO.net .

Comment: Why not use EF for Identity, and keep using ADO.NET for everything else?

Comment: Its just sake for simplicity to keep on using ADO.net as using different data access technologies will increase maintenance load in near future

Comment: I don't know of a way to separate Identity from EF. So you need to do a cost/benefit analysis. Is Identity worth using if it means you have to bring in EF? Or is there some other solution out there that doesn't require EF?

Answer (score 0):

Identity Framework would be connecting to your DB that has the ASPNet identity tables.  You give it a connection string, then things like the UserManager would access them on their own to get identity data.

If you then wanted to use ADO to access your other tables, I don't see why not.

(hopefully I hit the substance of your question.. )